# What should the Ask Different ads look like?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[I heard you guys all saying, "gee, I wish there were more meta posts from CHAOS for me to weigh in on," so I thought I'd oblige!]

We are toying with the idea of putting ads for Ask Different on Stack Overflow. Specifically, they'd go on the [osx] and [ios] tag pages, or perhaps on questions with those tags. We'll get [our awesome designer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) to put the actual ad together (though he doesn't know it yet...), but before we get to that point, we need some ideas.

The ad can be anything you want. It can be in the same style as the other ads running around the network that contain sample questions...

[image: which look like this]

...or it can be an image with a logo...

[image: which looks like this]

...or it can be anything else you guys want.

So! What are your ideas?

Comment: I would LOVE a flash ad with a Steve Jobs surrounded by flashing lights saying "You won a free iPad". Oh, and lots of sound!

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly have one or two appeal to people with strong opinions/ windows or linux background. Engaging / inviting them in would be good for the site.

---

Other random ideas in the hat are...

Maybe something like curious about the "mac side of the moon". (with a moon crescent silouette photo / just the words and the Ask Different icon in the corner)

Or a 2001 style rectangular object and a tag line - "My god, it's full of Apple answers"

It would have to be subtle and in good taste (and respectful of trademarks), but something that edged up to "what color is that kool-aid you have in your glass?" might be fun to work on.

Just some crazy half-baked ideas...

Comment: Are you suggesting the 'mac side of the moon' as a way to engage windows/linux folks like you suggested in your first line? Or is that a separate thought?

Comment: They all are independent - the idea of attracting win/Linux is an idea to kick around - then I made three theme suggestions that don't really play on Linux or windows from where I sit...

Comment: roger, was just wondering - "dark side of the moon" could sorta seem like a "come over to the dark side..." idea.

Comment: also: "that's no moon!"

Comment: Ha ha - indeed. The good designer might make it hard to tell which side of the moon was which - or even have it change yin/yang from top to bottom to make a point that perhaps your side isn't so fixed :-)

Comment: I love the 2001 idea. But it's sure to generate complaints that iPhone didn't even exist back then ;-)

Comment: Would love to see some mockups of these if you feel like it. Hint, hint, hint.